# How to enable/disable a button on parent modal popup from child in the IFrame using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to disable/enable a button of the parent window from the child window.

The following is a snippet from the parent page.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeTest" runat="server" 
  CancelControlID="btnClose" PopupControlID="pnl1" TargetControlID="showMpe"/>

<asp:Panel ID="pnl1" runat="server" >
           <ContentTemplate>
                <iframe id="ContentIframe" runat="server">
                        <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
                </iframe>
            </ContentTemplate>
    <p class="submitButton">
        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
        &nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="EnableDisable" />
    </p>
</asp:Panel>
```

In the child page that is loaded in the iframe, I have a grid view with LinkButtons. I am attempting to get one of these LinkButtons to disable/enable the btnTest from the parent window.

I have tried many things but I can't seem to figure this out... 
for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('[id$="linkButtonDisable"]').click(function() {
           window.parent.opener.document.getElementById("btnTest").disabled = true;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can anyone please help me out. I am fairly new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should try something like this...

```
$("#<%=linkButtonDisable.ClientID %>").click(function() {

       //Option N#1 HTML Attribute 
       $("#<%=btnTest.ClientID %>").attr("disabled","disabled");

       //Option 2 With jQueryMobile integration, the same it supposed to work if your using bootstrap, but I ignore the css class for disabling an element
       $("#<%=btnTest.ClientID %>").addClass("ui-disabled");

       //Also if you want to toggle states between disable/enable maybe this could work either...
       var id = $("#<%=btnTest.ClientID %>"); 
       var state = id.attr("disabled");
       //Dunno if it's needed to catch if disabled attr it isn't set
       if(state == "disabled") {
           id.removeAttr("disabled");
       } else {
           id.attr("disabled","disabled");
       }

});
```

Hope this help!...

Comment: Thanks, using the HTML attribute helped me out.